# MVC Restrict access to Admins

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Hello currently I am trying to make a feature on my website that will allow for admins to see one thing while regular users see another. Here is My code

```
 [RestrictAccess(restriction = AccessRestrictions.ModifySalesOrder)]        
        public ActionResult ChangeStatus(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
            }
            SalesOrder salesOrder = db.SalesOrders.Find(id);

            if (salesOrder == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }

            ViewBag.Invoice = false;
            ViewBag.enoughStock = true;


            switch (salesOrder.SalesOrderStatus)
            {
                case SOStatus.Pending:
                    ViewBag.statusList = new List<Object>             
                {
                    new {value = SOStatus.Pending, text = "Pending" },
                    new {value = SOStatus.Released, text = "Released" },

                };
                    break;

                case SOStatus.Released:

                    ViewBag.Invoice = true;

                    ViewBag.statusList = new List<Object>

               {

                    new {value = SOStatus.Shipped, text = "Shipped" },
                    new {value = SOStatus.Close, text = "Close" },

                };
                    break;
```

And here is my **groups model class**

```
public class Groups
    {
        [Key]
        public int ID { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Group Name")]
        public string GroupName { get; set; }
    }
    public class groupAccess
    {
        [Key]
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public AccessRestrictions restriction { get; set; }
        public bool allow { get; set; }
        public int groupID { get; set; }
    }
```

Here is the  **userAccess class** that assigns a user to a group ID

```
public class userAccess
    {
        [Key]
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public AccessRestrictions restriction { get; set; }
        public bool allow { get; set; }
        public int userID { get; set; }
        public int groupID { get; set; }
    }
```

I want the admins to have the capability to switch it back to pending when it is released but I don't want the users to have that capability. I have a groups model where I can assign users to be admins but my current problem is that I don't know how to "Restrict Access" so that it is only the "Admins" Group.

Thanks

Comment: Does your group model have a method to check if a user is in the admin group?

Comment: Yes, my only issue right now is I don't know how to limit it to the "Admins" group @TravisActon

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure there are other ways of doing this but here is one path:

You have a get method which you have shown. I am assuming you have a Post method as well to actually post the changes.

Your get method is just setting up a helpful UI for a valid submit post. It shouldn't be validating the change yet (do that in your post method) In your get method, for the case statement in question, first set your collection to it's own object. Then check if they are admin and append the option THEN assign it to your viewbag:

```
            case SOStatus.Released:

                ViewBag.Invoice = true;
                var options = new List<Object>{new {value = SOStatus.Shipped, text = "Shipped" }, new {value = SOStatus.Close, text = "Close" }};

                if(user is admin)
                  options.add(new {value=SOStatus.Pending, text = "Pending"});

               ViewBag.statusList = options;
               break;
```

On your post method you will recheck the original status before modification

If the original status = released and the new status = pending and the user is not in the admin group then you throw a bad request response.

Following this flow, you are setting up your UI for a user friendly successful post but if the user decides to try to hack the form submit, you can catch on your business logic.

If you have a ton of business logic and you are doing these checks regularly then you would probably be better off writing a wrapper around your SalesOrder class with validate methods. I don't know your requirements though so that may be over-engineering it in your case.

Comment: Awesome thanks Travis! What would be the correct syntax of (user = admin) though? I can't seem to figure out the correct way of checking. I'm new to this so I apologize for my ignorance

Comment: @chris no, that is not correct syntax, that is just paraphrasing your admin permission check method that you said you had. If you post that then we can help further.

Comment: Sorry I realized I misunderstood your initial comment. I don't have anything that checks if user is admin yet. But the group ID of "Admins" 1 so I was just going to do something like if user group id = 1 then give access. But obviously not the best way. I have updated the initial question. Thanks!

Comment: @chris in context to your group model: How is the user associated to a group?

Comment: Through the "userAccess" class. I'll add it in aswell

Comment: @chris So I'm guessing there is a userModel with a relationship to your userAccess class then as well? What type of authentication are you using?

Answer (score -1):

I don't have time for a full answer but try one of the following:

Check for current user:
((RolePrincipal)Usr).GetRoles()
and groups (there is a small session used for authentication). Then you can switch or redirect, let's say,
 httpredirect
OR
 if (rol='ADMIN') return ChangeStatus_Admin(…);
else return ChangeStatus_Others(…);

Good luck!